# Mongodb find data and groupby for another column

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5763e4d6c0140edcb8731485"),
        "_class" : "net.microservice.product.domain.Product",,
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-06-17T11:53:58.228Z"),
        "createdBy" : "user-0",
        "modifiedAt" : ISODate("2016-06-21T06:21:47.524Z"),
        "modifiedBy" : "user-0",
"merchant" : "a746f24safa5-e96f-4281-9759-a4a02b306d77",
        "type" : DBRef("productTypes", ObjectId("575fd99236623f70c959247f")),
    "fields" : {
        "Image4" : {
            "value" : "http://i.hizliresim.com/ZdELXa.jpg",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "CTA",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-06-21T06:21:47.204Z")
            }
        },
        "Image3" : {
            "value" : "http://i.hizliresim.com/l1WkqX.jpg",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "CTA",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-06-21T06:21:47.204Z")
            }
        },
        "Image2" : {
            "value" : "http://i.hizliresim.com/VYMl9n.jpg",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "CTA",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-06-21T06:21:47.204Z")
            }
        },
        "Kur" : {
            "value" : "TL",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "CTA",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-06-21T06:21:47.204Z")
            }
        },
        "Image1" : {
            "value" : "http://i.hizliresim.com/nrWAQ0.jpg",
            "detail" : {
                "revisedBy" : "CTA",
                "revisionDate" : ISODate("2016-06-21T06:21:47.204Z")
            }
        },
    "uploadDate" : ISODate("2016-06-17T11:53:00Z"),
    "tasks" : [ ]
}
```

this is sample of database. I want to get data in which:

```
- modifiedAt is before  "modifiedAt" : ISODate("2016-07-21T06:21:47.524Z"),
```

so i do this and this works:

```
    db.products.find({  
'modifiedAt': 
{$lte: ISODate("2016-10-18T13:05:18.961Z"
)}  }).
count()
    14999
```

But i need to find for each `merchant`. Beause 14999 result is not true because a merchant have lots of product so 14999 includes multiple products.

I need to group by merchant and distinct. I couldnot do it.

i do this but

```
db.products.
aggregate([ { 
$group: { 
_id: '$merchant', } }, {
$match: {
modifiedAt:
 {$lte: ISODate("2016-06-18T13:05:18.961Z")} }} ])
```

brings nothing and no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try something like this. This gives you the number of products by merchant.

```
db.products.aggregate([ 
    {$match: {modifiedAt:{$lte: ISODate("2016-06-21T06:21:47.524Z")}}},
    {$group: { _id: "$merchant",count: { $sum: 1 }}}
])
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : "a89846f24safa5-e96f-4281-9759-a4a02b306d77", "count" : 1 }
```

Comment: What is sum there, i couldnot understand it. the output is that` { "_id" : "ozdemirler_hali", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "a746fff245-e96f-42ff81-9759-a4a02b306d77", "count" : 75 }` it means 75 merchants? but why two touputs

Comment: It means 75 product rows for  that merchant. It's grouped by merchant, so you should see one output for each merchant.

Comment: i need to add ismatched:False but it doesnot work: `db.products.aggregate([     {
$match: {
{
modifiedAt:{$lte: ISODate("2016-10-18T06:21:47.524Z")},
{isMatched:false}
},{"isMatched" : false}},     {$group: { _id: "$merchant",count: { $sum: 1 }}} ])`

Comment: replace your match expresssion like this.    $match: {$and: [ { modifiedAt: {$lte: ISODate("2016-10-18T06:21:47.524Z") } }, { isMatched: { $eq: false } } ]}

Answer (score 0):

Always place the [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) as early in the aggregation pipeline as possible. Because $match limits the total number of documents in the aggregation pipeline, earlier $match operations minimize the amount of processing down the pipe.

So your query would be like

```
db.products.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      modifiedAt: {
        $lte: ISODate("2016-06-18T13:05:18.961Z")
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$merchant'
    }
  }
])
```